# vmware host and guest static ip address

Tags: connection, ip, vmware

i am new with networking. I have problem with the internet connection between the host system and guest os.(workstation 8)

I have laptop with win 7, which needs to have the static public IP(already working, internet connection OK). Guest OS is win server 2008 r2 sp1. I need to set static IP with the internet connection.(here is the problem i can't get it.)

i tried to set the NAT to share the host IP address, but the guest ip is always obtained from DHCP(but it must be static for example 192.168.1.22). When i set the same IP on the both machines, it will resolve to the IP conflict.

The problem can by that host ip is : 195.x.x.x(public) and guest ip is 192.x.x.x.

I appreciate any advice.

Thank you for your time.

S.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the network interface of your VM to "bridged" mode, so the VM will act like a machine of your network standing next to your computer.

Then, in the virtualized OS, you need to set the network interface to "static IP mode" with the adress you want.

This way it should work. (ping is your friend for diagnostics)

Note : Be careful of your guest firewall, still. It may find strange that packets from another machine are emitted from your machine and block them (I've seen it). In that case, check with WireShark.